# How do I save images/files in Django?

Tags: django

This might be a stupid question but I'm stuck.

I read the documentation on file/image uploads in Django here but I'm not sure how to proceed: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/http/file-uploads/

I have a model defined as below:

```
class PicUploads(models.Model):
    blog_post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='pics/%Y/%m/%d')

class PicUploadsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=PicUploads
        exclude = ('blog_post',)
```

In my views file, how do I go about saving the image?

If I use the handle_uploaded_file function as defined in the documentation, the image gets stored in the defined directory but what do I do to save its path along with the foreign key in the `PicUploads` model? Why can't I just use the `save()` method like I do with text data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`save()` is all you need to call on a `ModelForm` with a `File/ImageField`.

The document you are looking at explains how to use some upload handler to **customize the default behavior**, it's not required.

Just instantiate your modelform with `request.POST` and `request.FILES`, call `save()` and all is done!

```
form = Form(request.POST, request.FILES)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
```