# Failure to save a file in django

Tags: django

This is essentially a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353051/how-do-i-save-images-files-in-django) but the answer doesn't work for me.

I've tried this:

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

fs = FileSystemStorage(location='/a/legitimate/path)

class UploadedFile(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    file = models.FileField(storage=fs,upload_to='fits/')

class UploadFileForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    class Meta: 
        model = UploadedFile 
        fields = ('title', 'file')
```

but in my view, when I do:

```
    form = UploadFileForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid(): 
        form.save()
```

I get the following error:

```
no such table: upload_uploadedfile
```

What am I doing wrong?  I'm a total beginner to django and have found the documentation to be rather opaque, so I am probably doing something incredibly dumb.

Comment: Did you do a `django-admin.py syncdb` after creating your `UploadedFile` model? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#syncdb

Comment: I had forgotten to add my model to `INSTALLED_APPS`. Also, I needed to do `managedb.py syncdb`, not `django-admin.py syncdb`.    Thanks, though - you pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you do a django-admin.py syncdb after creating your UploadedFile model?

- http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#syncdb

The alternative is to run `python manage.py syncdb` from your project folder.